# Tips on saving distribution shape parameters to sqlite3

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have been playing around with distributions in Python using scipy. I have some code which produces a dataframe containing fit parameters for my various data fits. Example is shown below

```
fit = pd.DataFrame({'domain': ['T1','T1', 'T1'],
                    'type':['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'dist':['triang', 'triang', 'trapz'],
                    'shp':[(0.1, None), (0.1, None), (0.2, 0.8)],
                    'loc':[3, 100, 85],
                    'scale':[60, 50, 95]})
```

I have a range of these inputs using different distributions, so the shape parameters change and need to be kept in the right order. Therefore, when It is retrieved from the database, it will fit in with the distribution order.So for example, using the Triangle distribution: (c, d, loc, scale).

I have tried to convert the tuple to a string (keeping the brackets) so it can be viewed in the database. For example, for the 3rd row.

```
a = str(fit['shp'][2])
```

which produces `'(0.2, 0.8)'`. This can be saved to the Sqlite3 database.

However, I am not to sure how to convert it back to a tuple?

I did try,

```
b = tuple(a)
```

But this does not seem to produce the desired result, as shown below.

```
('(', '0', '.', '2', ',', ' ', '0', '.', '8', ')')
```

What would you guys recommend about saving the shape tuple to a database?

BJR

Comment: Save: convert tuples to list, save list as JSON. Read: Convert JSON to list, convert list to tuples.

Comment: Thanks Scotty, sorry its taken me so long to respond. This answer worked. Would you like to make this the answer?

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Feel free to answer your own question (maybe with a code sample) and mark it as accepted, it's a [valid procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on SO. Cheers =)